# How to detect bugs on POST request(flask)?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm new to flask. I was trying to apply post/redirect/get pattern to my program. Here is what I did.

In the index.html

```
{% block page_content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hello, {% if user %} {{ user }} {% else %} John Doe {% endif %}: {% if age %} {{ age }} {% else %} ?? {% endif %}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
    {% if form %}
    {{wtf.quick_form(form)}}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

In the views.py

```
class NameForm(Form):
    age = DecimalField('What\'s your age?', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

''''''
@app.route('/user/<user>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def react(user):
    session['user'] = user
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        old_age = session.get('age')
        if old_age != None and old_age != form.age.data:
            flash('age changed')
            session['age'] = form.age.data
        return redirect(url_for('react', user = user))
    return render_template('index.html', user = user, age = session.get('age'), form = form, current_time = datetime.utcnow())
```

The GET request is processed well when I open `xxxx:5000/user/abc`. However, the POST request fails. I get a 404 error. I think the `url_for` function may give a wrong value to `redirect`. How can I check the value returned by `url_for`?

I got a 405 error when I tried to use database. This time I have no clue.

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    form = SearchForm() # a StringField to get 'name' and SubmitField
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        person = Person.query.filter_by(name = form.name.data) # Person table has two attributes 'name' and 'age'
        if person is None:
            flash('name not found in database')
        else:
            session['age'] = person.age
            return redirect(url_for('search'))
    return render_template('search.html', form = form, age = session.get('age'), current_time = datetime.utcnow())
```

Is there a convenient way to debug when the POST request fails?

Comment: Run the app in [debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#debug-mode).

Comment: @nathancahill python run.py runserver --host 0.0.0.0 --debug This is what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't `url_for()`, it's the way you're using `wtf.quick_form()`. Take a look at the form generated by your code:

```
<form action="." method="post" class="form" role="form">
```

The `action="."` line tells the browser to take the information given and POST it to the URL `.`. The period (`.`) means "current directory." So what's happening is you're clicking submit, and then your browser POSTs to `localhost:5000/users/`. Flask sees this request to `/users/` and cannot serve it, because `/users/` isn't a valid URL. That's why you're getting a 404.

Fortunately, this can be fixed. In `index.html`, try calling `quick_form()` and passing in an action:

```
{{wtf.quick_form(form, action=url_for('react', user=user))}}
```

Now, your form is rendered like this:

```
<form action="/user/abc" method="post" class="form" role="form">
```

and your browser knows to POST the form to `/user/abc`, which is a valid URL, so Flask will handle it.

You didn't post your code for `search.html`, but try applying the same logic above to that template as well; hopefully that'll fix the issue!

Comment: Thank you very much!. Your. Where can I find the `<form ....>`?  Does `url_for('react', user = user)` work the same as `{{wtf.quick_form(form, action=url_for('react', user=user))}}`? In fact, I wrote the `react` view function yesterday, and it worked well. It failed today after I did some modifications.

Comment: 1. You can find the `<form>` element on the rendered page. Go to http://localhost:5000/user/abc then right click on the page and hit "view page source" (this might be called "view source").

2. In short, no, they're not the same. `url_for()` is a Python function that returns a string which is the URL for a function ([see here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for)). `wtf.quick_form()` is a Jinja2 macro which renders a form ([see here](https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/blob/master/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/wtf.html#L131)).